# Generate json from object with renamed keys

Tags: json, groovy

I want to convert my POGO to json, but with the keys being all lowercase.

```
class Device {
  MoreInfo moreInfo

  ...some other fields...
}

class MoreInfo {
  String thisIsCamelCase
}
```

When I use `new JsonBuilder(device).toPrettyString()` the keys are copied from the member name (i.e. are in camel case). However I want both "moreInfo" and "thisIsCamelCase" keys to be lowercase. Is there a neat way to achieve this?

Solutions I've come across include using JsonSlurper to converter to a map and then renaming the keys manually (remove obj from map, and re-add with new name) and converting back to Json.

Is there some Groovy equivalent of `@JsonProperty`?

Comment: No, I think you need to either rebuild the map with the new keys (as you say) or use Jackson (or similar) with `@JsonProperty` (as you also say)

Answer (score 0):

The following script makes all the map keys lowercase:

```
import groovy.transform.Field

def m = [A:1, B:2, c:[D:2]]

@Field
def c = { k, v -> [(k.toLowerCase()):(v in Map)? v.collectEntries(c): v] }

assert m.collectEntries(c) == [a:1, b:2, c:[d:2]]
```